# Stable group as colimit of finitely generated stable subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, category-theory

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $0$ and $X$ a subgroup of the algebraic closure $\overline{K}$ which is stable under the absolute Galois group $G_K$. We can write $X$ as the colimit of its finitely generated subgroups $H$ (by some abstract nonsense) but can we choose these $H$ to also be stable under the $G_K$-action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; this doesn't follow by abstract nonsense but requires the specific property of the $G_K$ action that it has finite orbits. Namely, first write $X$ as the increasing union of finitely generated subgroups $X_i$ as usual. Then, each $X_i$ can be replaced with a $G_K$-stable finitely generated subgroup given by acting on each of the generators of $X_i$ by $G_K$. Since the action has finite orbits the result is still finite.

In general, if we had a group $X$ acted on by another group $G$ the best we'd be able to say is that $X$ is the increasing union of $G$-stable subgroups which are "finitely $G$-generated" in the sense that they are generated by a finite set of elements together with the $G$-action, or equivalently generated by a finite set of orbits of the $G$-action.

Comment: Perfect. Nothing more to add. And answered in record time. Thank you